How do I tell gcc to shut up about forward declaring struct inside parameter list?
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignore ???
int fstat(int handle, struct stat *statbuf); 
/* to get struct stat, #include <asm/stat.h> */
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

I've gotten most of the way there, but in order to fill out the ignore pragma I need to know what to put there instead of ???.
This file just declares the asm stubs. Most users of this header file won't care about struct stat but one does. I will be disappointed if I have to make another header file for one line of declaration.

How about you forward declare it outside of the parameter list ?

You should have read and thought about the full error message from GCC: “'struct stat' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration”. If you had successfully suppressed the diagnostic, you would have solved the problem “My code gets an error message,” but you would still have the problem “struct stat is not visible outside this declaration.” Do not leave mistakes in your program. Eliminate the mistakes, not the messages.

@EricPostpischil: One of two things happens; either #include <asm/stat.h> was performed and struct stat is defined, or it isn't and calling the function isn't practical anyway.

Why can't this file include <asm/stat.h> ? After all it seem to be depending on it.

@EugeneSh.: 3 of 4 files that include it have no use of asm/stat.h though.

Does it harm in any way? Unless you have some conflicting declarations/definitions, it should not (well, except a slightly longer compile time).

Add struct stat; before the function declaration.

By the way, the "correct" header in a POSIX compliant system for both the structure and the function declarations is <sys/stat.h>.

@Someprogrammerdude: Irrelevant and misleading; the syscall copy of the stat structure and the glibc copy disagree. While the declaration of fstat is the same, the declaration of the stat structure is not.

This would be one of the rare cases where the oddball scope rule of function prototype scope applies (6.2.1).

@Joshua But you are calling the POSIX function so you should be using the POSIX header. The type of struct stat and the syscall called by POSIX fstat may change depending on how the code is compiled, especially for a 32-bit architecture where it will depend on the __FILE_OFFSET_BITS and __TIME_BITS macro values for Linux/glibc.

@IanAbbott: I am most definitely not linking against glibc.

@Joshua Are you trying to implement your own fstat?

@IanAbbott: I have. It's only 5 lines of assembly. asm/stat.h is correct. But if I change my link steps and use musl-libc for another program, then sys/stat.h is correct.

Without a prior declaration of struct stat, the given function declaration declares this struct type inside of the parameter list, and this declaration isn't visible outside the declaration, hence the error.
Rather than added compiler specific flags to ignore the error, declare the struct outside of the declaration.
struct stat;
int fstat(int handle, struct stat *statbuf); 

Since you're not actually using struct stat, you only need the declaration.
